# Characterizing errors in rotation and translation while estimating camera pose from images

Tags: computer-vision, error-handling

Has anyone characterized the errors in rotation and translation while estimating camera pose of natural images using SFM or visual odometry? I mean, when estimating camera pose, what is the typical amount of error in rotation and translation that one can expect?

Any references on errors in odometry sensors are also welcome.